# Creating a bulleted list on a label widget using python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to create a hanging indented list using the tkinter label widget? Note: Using propper standard bullets not * or -.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-September/552013.html). It uses a Text widget instead of a Label for much more flexibility. I would advise using `u2022` as the bullet point instead of `u00B7` though. If you don't want to allow editing, add `txt.configure(state=DISABLED)`.

Comment: @fhdrsdg That's great thank you, didn't realize you could disable editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use unicode code points, as a rough implementation:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

class BulletLabel(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        text = kwargs.pop('text', '')
        kwargs['text'] = self.bulletise(text)
        tk.Label.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

    def bulletise(self, text):
        if len(text) == 0: # no text so no bullets
            return ''
        lines = text.split('\n')
        parts = []
        for line in lines: # for each line
            parts.extend(['\u2022', line, '\n']) # prepend bullet and re append newline removed by split
        return ''.join(parts)

    def configure(self, *args, **kwargs):
        text = kwargs.pop('text', '')
        if text != '':
            kwargs['text'] = self.bulletise(text)
        tk.Label.configure(*args, **kwargs)


root = tk.Tk()

blabel = BulletLabel(root, text='one\ntwo\nthree')
blabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

I have made a class that do what you want:

```
class BLabel(object):
    b = "•"
    def __init__(self,master):
        import tkinter as tk
        self.l = tk.Label(master)
    def add_option(self,text):
        if self.l.cget("text") == "":
            self.l.config(text=self.b+" "+text)
        else:
            self.l.config(text=self.l.cget("text") +"\n"+ self.b + " "+text)
```

You can use it like:

```
lbal = BLabel(master=master)    
lbal.add_option("Bullet1")    #<-- adding item
lbal.add_option("Bullet2")    #<-- adding item
lbal.l.pack()     #<-- Packing
```

Here is an example code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class BLabel(object):
    b = "•"
    def __init__(self,master):
        import tkinter as tk
        self.l = tk.Label(master)
    def add_option(self,text):
        if self.l.cget("text") == "":
            self.l.config(text=self.b+" "+text)
        else:
            self.l.config(text=self.l.cget("text") +"\n"+ self.b + " "+text)



lbal = BLabel(master=root)
lbal.add_option("Bullet1")
lbal.add_option("Bullet2")
lbal.l.pack()
```

Here is the output of above code:

[image: bullet in tkinter label]

In that way, you can use `pack` , `place` or `grid`. Example:

**Grid:**

```
lbal.l.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

**Place:**

```
lbal.l.place(x=0,y=0)
```

**Pack:**

```
lbal.l.pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off with a message widget, which is a label widget designed to show text with multiple lines. For your bullets you can use a unicode string. For example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

point = '\u2022'
msg = tk.Message(root, text='Hello\n%s World.' % point)
msg.pack()
```